# R- Special Characters are not inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql, r

How to insert the special characters into MySQL using r programming?

I have a data frame which will read data from a tsv file. I want to insert these values into mysql database data frame contains 2000 rows. But it is inserting only 23 rows. I am using RODBC library.

The problem was the special characters inside the data.

The sample data:

1. Ouça a música
2. Sony"s

Error:

```
Error in sqlSave(conn, data4, "test.solution8", append = TRUE, verbose = TRUE,  : 
      [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
    HY000 1366 [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.11]Incorrect string value: '\xE7a a m...' for column 'fullcontent' at row 1
```

Comment: Can you set encoding (to utf-8)?

Comment: These should help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @ Roman Lustrik - Can you please tell me how to set the encoding?

Comment: @ Nico the problem here is not in mysql. everything is working fine in msql. i tried to insert tat particular code. it is inserted. only coming from r it is not inserting.

Comment: @ Roman Lustrik - i tried to set encoding utf-8. however, it is not working. again same error

Answer (score 1):

Your database, program and the connection each have an encoding.

Make sure your connection uses the same encoding as your database

```
ch<-odbcConnect("mydb",DBMSencoding="UTF-8");
```

This was also discussed in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653430/how-to-set-charset-for-mysql-in-rodbc).

Comment: code i tried is d<- data.frame("ドと「宇宙戦艦ヤ"); sqlSave(conn, d, "sma.test", append=TRUE, verbose=TRUE, rownames=F, colnames=FALSE);

Comment: Character strings in R can be declared to be encoded in "latin1" or "UTF-8" or as "bytes". Your string isn't probably right even before you call your sql statement. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html