# R: How can I get correctly special characters from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, r, ggplot2, special-characters

I'm newbie in R and I'm creating an statistics graphics with ggplot2. Everything is OK but I have found that some characters are not printing correctly like ÁÉÍÓÚ or Ç or Ñ or Ü.

When I get the data from MySQL I get incorrect characters. Like you can see in the next image. In this image the character "Ñ" or "Ç" is replaced by

[image]

How can I get these special characters correctly from MySQL?

**Edit I:**

One screencap from my database where you can see that the special characters are saved correctly:

[image]

Comment: I assume you used utf8 encoding in the MySQL tables?  Try the query `SET NAMES utf8` first before you query the table information to set the connection into using utf8 encoding

Comment: My tables are defined with CHARACTER SET 'latin1' and COLLATE 'latin1_spanish_ci'

Comment: latin1 does not support "special characters" like `Ñ` or `Ç` you need to use utf8

Comment: I have updated my original post where you can see that "special characters" like Ñ or Ç are saved correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903814/r-special-characters-are-not-inserting-in-mysql