# RMySQL encoding issue on Windows - Spanish Character ñ

Tags: mysql, r, encoding, utf-8

While using RMySQL::dbWriteTable function in R to write a table to MySQL on Windows I get an error message concerning the character [ñ].

The simplified example is:

```
    table <- data.frame(a=seq(1:3), b=c("És", "España", "Compañía"))
    table

 a        b
1 1       És
2 2   España
3 3 Compañía


db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "####", password = "####", dbname ="test", host= "localhost")

RMySQL::dbWriteTable(db, name="test1", table, overwrite=T, append=F )

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Invalid utf8 character string: 'Espa'
```

As you can see, there is no problem with the accents ("És") but there is with the ñ character ("España").

On the other hand, there is no problem with MySQL since this query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO test.test1 (a,b)
values (1, "España");
```

Things I have already tried previous to write the table:

1. Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8" for all table.
2. iconv(x, "UTF-8", "UTF-8") for all table.
3. Sent pre-query: dbSendQuery(db, "SET NAMES UTF8;")
4. Change MySQL table Collation to: "utf-8-general, latin-1, latin-1-spanish...)

*Tried "Latin-1" encoding and didn't work either.

I have been looking for an answer to this question for a while with no luck.
Please help!

Versions:

MySQL 5.7.17

R version 3.3.0

Sys.getlocale()

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C"
```

PS: Works fine in Linux environment but I am stuck with Windows in my current project :(

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Windows, an OS that uses UTF16 since its inception (OK, UCS2 up to ~2000). MySQL does have issues since it doesn't support Unicode natively (ie as `nvarchar`) but depends on varchar fields with a UTF8 collation. That *does* lead to problems, if an application saves ASCII data with a different codepage to the field.

Comment: Most of the time, the problem is the application itself, especially in C and C++. Instead of using multi-byte or Unicode types (char16_t, utf16string), applications use ASCII buffers and types and to store UTF8-encoded strings. To be fair, these were added in C++11.  R is notorious for this - R itself compiles with Unicode support on Windows, but third-party packages are often inconsistent. Some use Unicode, some allow you to specify a locale, and the worst case, some depend on the user's locale to specify the codepage, just like any non-Unicode application

Comment: Before saying "it's a Windows problem", imagine having to work with data from *multiple* locales. You can't hard-code just *one* locale in `LC_COLLATE` when you have to deal with multiple codepages

Comment: Check [How to set charset for MySQL in RODBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653430/how-to-set-charset-for-mysql-in-rodbc) RODBC allows you to set the connection's character set to UTF8.

Comment: I was able to isolate the problem to the *GUI*. RStudio 1.0.136 and Rgui silently convert Unicode literals. Whatever you type is treated as a non-Unicode string. On my machine (Greek Locale), the `ñ` was converted to `n`. [R Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/rtvs/)  on the other hand doesn't have this issue, the characters were preserved

Comment: This RStudio support article on [Character Encoding](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding) suggests saving your scripts as UTF8 **and** change the default encoding to UTF8. This also preserves the encoding. If you *don't* set the default encoding, you'll have to open the script as UTF8 using `File > Reopen with Encoding`

Comment: Thanks for the insights Panagiotis! I have tried RODBC but didn't work either. Finally I used a Windows server and it worked! So I suppose there is a problem with my local PC configuration (most probably on R config). I will force the server R conf to my PC and see if it works...

Comment: It's not the *system* configuration, or even ODBC, it's getting R to treat strings/scripts as UTF8 instead of the system locale. I couldn't even get RStudio to display `ñ` in a Greek locale until I changed the default encoding to UTF8. How do you run the scripts? Did you save them as UTF8? As for RODBC, you can set the charset either through the DBMSEncoding setting or by executing a set of commands [as shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653430/how-to-set-charset-for-mysql-in-rodbc). The strings have to arrive intact to the driver in the first place though

Comment: Another option is to avoid the entire script encoding problem by *loading* the data from a file, eg a UTF8 encoded file. The client can't mangle a string literal if it never gets to see it

Comment: As for the short explanation for the trouble - Windows are Unicode, and built to accomodate multiple users with multiple recional settings and an international market. The system locale is the "Language used for non-Unicode programs". That's why there is no UTF8 locale - what's the point? Non-Unicode applications were shamed to extinction back in 2000.

Comment: R was built on Linux, using Linux assumptions though, where UTF8 is  treated as one more encoding that saves space over UTF16, doesn't require changing the existing C code. You can still use `char*`. That's *not* a bad assumption to make on a server OS - processes don't change their encodings while running, scripts and programming languages are written in US ASCII, the bulk of HTML pages is also US ASCII even if it contains non-English text. Unfortunately, when R was ported to Windows, the non-Unicode `char*` strings remained and were treated as non-Unicode strings using the system encoding

Comment: I found an intermediate solution. Since not only Spanish character were impeding the upload process (other special characters such long dash [--] and weird spaces imported from Excel files), I apply `make.names` function to all the column and it clean all these special characters. I know it is not the best solution but allows me to cross tables since they are all imported the same way (using make.names).

Comment: Why do this instead of saving and loading the script as Unicode? There's nothing wrong with *Windows*. It's just a setting in `General`. No problems with long dashes or Excel files either *provided they **are** Excel files*, not just CSVs with a fake extension. In fact, when you *load* the files, you can specify the encoding to use. What would you do if you worked on Linux and had to load German, Russian and Ukranian ASCII files at once (true story, beer bottling factory in Ukraine)? Wouldn't you specify the encoding for each file?

Comment: Don't use Greek locale; it does not include tilde-n.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, it looks like it is a problem of the encoding setup of the connection. By default my connection was setup to utf-8 but my local encoding was setup to latin1. Therefore, my final solution was:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user=user, password=password,dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port)
# With the next line I try to get the right encoding (it works for Spanish keyboards)
encoding <- if(grepl(pattern = 'utf8|utf-8',x = Sys.getlocale(),ignore.case = T)) 'utf8' else 'latin1'
dbGetQuery(con,paste("SET names",encoding))
dbGetQuery(con,paste0("SET SESSION character_set_server=",encoding))
dbGetQuery(con,paste0("SET SESSION character_set_database=",encoding))
dbWriteTable( con, value = dfr, name = table, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE )
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Windows:

```
write.csv(table, file = "tmp.csv", fileEncoding = "utf8", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "####", password = "####", dbname ="test", host= "localhost")

dbWriteTable( db, value = "tmp.csv", name = "test1", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",", quote='\"', eol="\r\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with a data table of about 60 columns and 1.5 million rows; there were many computed values and reconciled and corrected dates and times so I didn't want to reformat anything I didn't have to reformat. Since  the utf-8 issue was only coming up in character fields, I used a kludgy-but-quick approach:

1) copy the field list from the `dbWriteTable` statement into a word processor or text editor

2) on your copy, keep only the fields that have descriptions as VARCHAR and TEXT

3) strip those fields down to just field names

4) use paste0 to write a character vector of statements that will ensure all the fields are character fields:

```
dt$x <- as.character(dt$x)
```

5) then use paste0 again to write a character vector of statements that set the encoding to `UTF-8`

```
Encoding(dt$x) <- "UTF-8"
```

Run the `as.character` group before the `Encoding` group.

It's definitely a kludge and there are more elegant approaches, but if you only have to do this now and then (as I did), then it has three advantages:

1) it only changes what needs changing (important when, as with my project, there is a great deal of work already in the data table that you don't want to risk in a reformat),

2) it doesn't require a lot of space and read/writes in the intermediate stage, and

3)it's fast to write and runs at an acceptable speed for at least the size of data table I'm working with.

Not elegant, but it will get you over this particular hitch very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The function dbConnect() has a parameter called encoding that can help you easily setup the connection encoding method.

```
dbConnect(MySQL(), user=user, password=password,dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, encoding="latin1")
```

This has allowed me to insert "ñ" characters into my tables and also inserting data into columns that have "ñ" in their name. For example, I can insert data into a column named "año".